# How to break up long words in a views display?

Tags: views, theming

I have a "related discussion" block view. Long words like links are breaking my layout.

Is there a way to force line breaks on those long words?

I could limit the length of links that then they wouldn't be as useful.

[image]

**Update:** 
Turns out that the CSS doesn't work across all browsers and also wraps regular words in funny ways sometimes.

Is there a way to do this in Drupal?

Comment: never mind, CSS to the rescure: word-break: break-all; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div

Comment: Send us the link of your site and I will send you the css code to fix this

Comment: thx. I was able to fix it with above help.

Comment: How do questions like this get closed off?

Comment: Not sure if the moderators can do that or if I have to post and answer and accept it. ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no universal solutions to this issue. But the currently acceptable ones are to use the `wbr` HTML tag (perhaps with some JS), or to, as you have seen, use `break-word` (as opposed to Chrome's break-all) along with some fallbacks. Both of these solutions are [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514061/word-wrapbreak-word-alternative). Drupal.org uses or used to use the `word-wrap: break-word;` solution.

Comment: Go with the `word-wrap` solution it works great: http://jsfiddle.net/daQ9H/2/ :)